# Replace Emoticons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Is it possible to replace a word with emoticons?

For example

NSString *myString = @"I am sad of him"

now i want to check the word whether it contains the word "sad", if it has i want to replace that word with sad emoticons.

I am not sure how to have emoticons in the nsstring

Please let me know

Comment: Are you refering to having an *actual image* inside of your string, or just a couple of characters, like :), :(?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah, you can do this using this:

```
myString = [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"sad" withString:@"\ue058"];
```

Check this link for emoji codes: (replace the &#x with \u though)
http://barrow.io/posts/iphone-emoji/

Comment: This link to the emoji codes is now broken.  Is there any more pages with the emoji codes?

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSAttributed String to show emotion icon but before that you have to search "sad" word in whole paragraph  by using normal search method. :)