# iphone Emoji icons are not displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am displaying emoji icons i my app, it was working fine when i was using as like in the below link
[Replace Emoticons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820963/replace-emoticons)

But when stored the same unicode into db, it just displays as text "\ue058"

why this is happening, please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The test you have in your question is different than the text in the answer to your other question

From the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820963/replace-emoticons):

```
myString = [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"sad" withString:@"\ue058"];
```

"/ue058" != "\ue058"

That may be your issue.

Without more information about how the string is being stored in the database and how it is being displayed that is my best guess.